# How to give name to BoxView in xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms app and Instead of entry I want to use Boxview and Iam trying to name the Boxview and the following error is displayed 
 here is the code

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <!--<Entry x:Name="csv_file" Placeholder="" WidthRequest="150">
     </Entry>-->
            <BoxView x:Name="csv_file" Color="WhiteSmoke" WidthRequest="150" 
     HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        />
            <Button BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="Black" 
        WidthRequest="60" Text="...." Clicked="OnBrowse"/>

        </StackLayout>
```

The error is

Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'BoxView' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'BoxView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can you suggest me if I have to add any assembly references ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to figure out which element/property is causing the problem.  Try removing them both, then add one back, then add each property, etc, until you find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use BoxView instead of an Entry. BoxView doesn't have Text property.

Xamarin.Forms [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview/):

> BoxView renders a simple rectangle of a specified width, height, and
>   color. You can use BoxView for decoration, rudimentary graphics, and
>   for interaction with the user through touch.

Comment: to display and enter text I need something like a Boxview structure instead of entry can you please suggest me what can be used instead of boxview ?

Comment: If by "structure" you mean appearances, you can write a custom Entry renderer. More info: [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: can you please tell me what should be used for drop down button i tried various codes but all of them threw errors stating the dropdown doesn't exist

Comment: Take a look at these links: [Xamarin Views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views/) - [Button](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Button/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the code-behind for the view. From the commented out code, it looks like you used to have an `<Entry>` with the same name, and you probably have code that attempts to set `csv_file.Text`, which might have worked for `Entry`, but won't for `BoxView` of course.